# Regex pattern for a password

Tags: regex, validation, passwords

I need a regex pattern that validates a password format.
The rules are:

- Minimum 8 chars in total
- at least two letters
- at least two digits or symbols

I came up with the following:
`/((?=.*[0-9\@\&#\$\?\%!\|(){}[]])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,})/`

It will look if both occure once, but I need it toch validate if they occur at least twice. 
If I add the `{2,}` like this:
`/((?=.*[0-9\@\&#\$\?\%!\|(){}[]]{2,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z]{2,}).{8,})/`

Then the following doesnt work for example: a1a1a1a1a1

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you do it, using positive lookaheads: http://regex101.com/r/uW0yI4

`/^(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z])(?=.*[!"#...\d].*[!"#...\d]).{8,}$/gmi`

Just replace `!"#...` with all the symbols you want to match.

Note: the multiline flag might be unnecessary for your applications.

Comment: This works, only one small remark, it will accept unallowed chars like ~ too. How can I stop that?

Comment: Change the `.` dot to a character class containing what you want to allow. For example: `/^(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z])(?=.*[!"#...\d].*[!"#...\d])[a-z\d]{8,}$/gmi`

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you're after:

```
^((?=(.*[\d0-9\@\&#\$\?\%!\|(){}[\]]){2,})(?=(.*[a-zA-Z]){2,}).{8,})$
```